# type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'double?' in type cast in ExpansionTile after removing one of the list Item flutter

Tags: flutter, key, store, flutter-listview, expansion-tile

I've been made a list of Card and ExpansionTile with a list view builder, because of saving last values in textformfields I've used key for ExpansionTile  as a type of PageStorKey,
everything works good but after removing one of the item of list, this error happen,

```
The following _CastError was thrown building SingleChildScrollView(dependencies:
[PrimaryScrollController]):
type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'double?' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.restoreScrollOffset (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:420:103)
#1      new ScrollPosition (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:105:7)
#2      new ScrollPositionWithSingleContext (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:56:8)
#3      ScrollableState._updatePosition (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:406:10)
#4      ScrollableState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:431:5)
```

i have searched a lot in git and stack but didn't find any solution ,
this is My Code:

```
List<dynamic> RefrigCarNo = [];


ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: RefrigCarNo.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            color: getColor(context, index),
            key:new PageStorageKey(RefrigCarNo[0].elementAt(index)), <=I do it as string but didnt answer
            child: ExpansionTile(
              maintainState: CollapseState,
              title:RichText(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: label_A,
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(text: 'refrigCar'),
                        TextSpan(text: ' ${RefrigCarNo[index][1].toString()} '
                      ]
                  )
              ),
              children: [
                Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 3),
                  width: PageWidth * 0.4,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Kg Of Material', style: label_A,),
                      AppTextField1(
                        MyController: Weight,
                        MyValidation: false,
                        typeOfInput: TextInputType.number,
                        myReadOnly: readOnlyChange,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 3),
                  width: PageWidth * 0.3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Total Net', style: label_A,),
                      AppTextField1(
                        MyController: NetCalcWeight,
                        MyValidation: false,
                        typeOfInput: TextInputType.number,
                        myReadOnly: readOnlyChange,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
```

this is removing function that defined in a button which include index of item:

```
void onDeleteVar(int _index) async{ 
 setState(() {
  RefrigCarNo.removeAt(_index);
  });
}
```

Comment: Any further details surrounding the error that gets logged?

Comment: edited to all of details, it belongs to  key:new PageStorageKey I think!